# What is this Solitaire games name

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

There are 7 rows:

**Row 1**  7 Face up
**Row 2**  1 down 6 up
**Row 3**  2 down 5 up
**Row 4**  3 down 4 up
**Row 5**  4 down 3 up
**Row 6**  5 down 2 up
**Row 7**  6 down 1 up

Any of the 3 remaining cards can be played to bottom of a row IE 9 spades on 10 spades, if there are no moves possible.

Aces are played to discard piles when only at bottom of row
cards are played from any row position to the bottom of corresponding row
IE 8 of spades is played below 9 of spades which must be last card in the row.

Game is won when all 4 suites are played ace to king.
Game is lost if no moves can be made.

Comment: This sounds like the common Klondike solitaire with three variations, but nothing I've heard of before. Do you have any more information about it (even where you learned it could help to identify local variations)?

Comment: Heard of the game from a cousin, who didn't know the name either. I have a picture of the game layout but could not figure out how to add it.

Comment: The most similar game seems to be "Applegate". It has the same rules as you describe but a different layout with fewer cards face-down. It also doesn't have separate piles for the aces. Rules here: https://www.goodsol.com/pgshelp/index.html?applegate.htm

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but it's not it